# Is there a way to get Powershell 5's Get-Help to parse the current script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have a trivially simple script:

```
function a-func {

}

<#
.Synopsis
  Testing Get-Help
#>
function another-func {

}

Get-Help another-func
```

I don't have a machine with Powershell 3 or 4 on it to double-check, but I seem to remember that this worked prior to PS 5.  In a Powershell 5.0 console, this is the output:

> C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell> .\testhelp.ps1
>   Get-Help : Get-Help could not find another-func in a help file in this
>   session. To download updated help topics type: "Update-Help". To get
>   help online, search for the help topic in the TechNet library at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=107116. At
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\testhelp.ps1:13
>   char:1
>   + Get-Help another-func
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Get-Help], HelpNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HelpNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand

I have tried placing the help comment both just before the function as well as inside of it.

Is this a regression in Powershell 5, or am I doing it wrong?  The goal is to get the help output on a per-function basis from within the script.

A little more detail:

```
> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      0      10105  0

> [System.Environment]::OSVersion

Platform ServicePack Version    VersionString
-------- ----------- -------    -------------
 Win32NT             6.3.9600.0 Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0
```

Comment: I just tried to reproduce the issue in Powershell 4.0 and could not.

Comment: I've filed a connect bug on this as well: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedbackdetail/view/1370636/get-help-doesnt-parse-current-script-regression-in-powershell-v5

Comment: I tried your code on Server 2016 TP2 with PowerShell 5 and it works just fine. PSVersion is `5.0.10074.0`

Comment: @PeterHahndorf I don't have a Server 2016 box, but I have a Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1; the problem is reproducible on both

Comment: I tried `Windows Management Framework 5.0 Preview February 2015` on a fresh `Windows Server 2012 R2`. Your code works fine. PSVersion is `5.0.10018.0` I then tried `Windows Management Framework 5.0 Preview April 2015` PSVersion `5.0.10105.0` and it still works. Just sayin.

Comment: Ugh, confirmed.  Thanks for checking for me.  Now the sucky part: what thing in my environment is doing this to me?

Comment: Has anything been identified in your environment? I'm having the same issue in PSVersion `5.0.10130` on Windows 10 version `10.0.10130.0`. I confirmed that this works in PS v2 with the exact same script.

Comment: Can you confirm your execution policy with `Get-ExecutionPolicy`? I was having the same issue, and actually ran `Set-ExecutionPolicy` without error, but it didn't set the value I passed. I had to add `-Force` to get it to take and then Get-Help worked as expected.

Comment: @beavel my policy is currently `RemoteSigned`

Comment: @beavel what did you set your policy to when it worked?

Comment: @BenCollins Here is the command I ran `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser -Force` so I did `RemotSigned`. Can you run scripts just fine? The example works just fine for me when pasted into the console with `Restricted` set, but won't when I save the example to a file. One other thing I noticed was that it shows progress bar for CIM similar to getting help for DSC resources.

Comment: `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser -Force` solved the problem for me on Windows 10

Comment: Running `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser -Force` didn't help for me unfortunately. :(
Version: 5.1.14393.1066 on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Comment-based help for a function can appear in one of three locations:

- At the beginning of the function body.
- At the end of the function body.
- Before the Function keyword. There cannot be more than one blank line between the last line of the function help and the Function keyword.

Microsoft link on this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-5.0

Try:

```
function a-func {
}
function another-func {
<#
    .Synopsis
    Testing Get-Help
#>
}
```

Paste the code in powershell ISE, highlight the functions and hit F8 then run the following in the console pane:

```
PS> Get-Help another-func
```

**Sorry if there are any formatting issues, answered this from my phone